# ECMA script for checking active workflows for an list item

Tags: workflow, javascript

Hi i am having more than 1 workflow associated with the list if there is any workflow that is active for an item then i need to prevent starting another workflow for the same item. I am using the following code to achieve the same. Can anyone please provide me the ECMA client script object model equivalent for achieving the same.

```
//Check for any active workflows for the document
    private void CheckForActiveWorkflows()
    {
        // Parameters 'List' and 'ID' will be null for site workflows.
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["List"]) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.Params["ID"]))
        {
            this.workflowList = this.Web.Lists[new Guid(Request.Params["List"])];
            this.workflowListItem = this.workflowList.GetItemById(Convert.ToInt32(Request.Params["ID"]));

        }
        SPWorkflowManager manager = this.Site.WorkflowManager;
        SPWorkflowCollection workflowCollection = manager.GetItemActiveWorkflows(this.workflowListItem);
        if (workflowCollection.Count > 0)
            SPUtility.TransferToErrorPage("An workflow is already running for the document. Kindly complete it before starting a new workflow");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Marc Anderson's excellent SPServices library.

> SPServices is a jQuery library which abstracts SharePoint's Web Services and makes them easier to use.

Get it from [codeplex](https://spservices.codeplex.com/)

There is a [Workflow web service wrapper](https://spservices.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Workflow) that you can use to retrieve all active workflows on a given item.
The method you want to use is `GetWorkflowDataForItem`

```
var hasActiveWorkflows = false;
$().SPServices({
    operation: 'GetWorkflowDataForItem', 
    item: 'http://yoursite/yourDocLib/item',
    completefunc: function(data,status){
        hasActiveWorkflows = $(data.responseXML).find('ActiveWorkflowsData > Workflows').children().length > 0;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my query mdmazzotti. I will try your approach and update you the outcome soon.